# Expression Blend 4 and Curved Text

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I'm looking to create text follow a curved arch.  How can I go about this using Expression Blend 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comprehensive walk through is available on [electric beach](http://electricbeach.org/?p=653)

Comment: Boom!  That's the answer I was looking for.  Thanks Aaron!